# websphere application server profiles

Tags: websphere, was, wcs

What creates the profiles under {install_dir}/IBM/WebSphere/Appserver/profiles

I'm working on RHEL.  Installed WAS 7 and WebSphere Commerce.  All of this is scripted given to me by others.

At some point a folder gets created under profiles.  However, I must have done something to mess this up, because on subsequent attempts to repeat this on new servers the folder doesn't get created.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere application server profiles are created and managed either using [IBM Profile Management Tool (PMT) GUI](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tpro_instances.html) or the command line version, [manageProfiles](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.migration.base.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_manageprofiles.html) in the bin dir.  More general infomation about profiles can be found in this [IBM KnowledgeCenter topic.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tpro_instancessaappserv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  This is WAS meets Commerce.  So the WAS "profile" gets created when Commerce creates what it calls an "instance".  On my system, this is performed within the script:

{scripts}/IBM_WCS/instance_Creation.sh

Whether that comes from the vendor or is an invention of my predecessor, I have no idea.  But once I got that to run, the profile appeared.